# Unable to Get CakePHP Cookbook Simple ACL Example Working

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

I'm having problems getting ACL working with CakePHP.  I've been working with the CakePHP Cookbook 2.0 example [Simple Acl controlled Application](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html?highlight=app_controller), and have gone through the steps twice, but I've run into the same problem both times.

Everything appears to be setup correctly.

- I'm able to create my groups, and users.
- The **aros** table appears to have the same rows shown in the example on the web.
- The **acos** and **aros_acos** tables appear to get populated with values that resemble the article.
- And when I visit a page that's setup to be protected, I'm presented with the login page.

But when I login using the account I created, I see the following error:

```
Warning (512): DbAcl::check() - 
Failed ARO/ACO node lookup in permissions check.  Node     references:
Aro: Array
(
[User] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [username] => dc
        [email] => myemail@somedomain.com
        [group_id] => 1
        [created] => 2011-10-27 14:58:59
        [modified] => 2011-10-27 14:58:59
    )
)  
Aco: /Posts/add [CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/AclComponent.php, line 303]
```

That account is setup as an administrator, and the administrator group has been granted access to everything ... so if it works, I shouldn't have a problem ... but it seems like there's a lower-level problem that's getting in my way.  I can post my DB tables as well if that'd be helpful, but figured I'd start here.  Thanks for any insight you can provide.

Comment: I used to work with cake and that ACL Plugin has more problems than carter has pills. Just a heads up. Try http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-cakephps-access-control-lists/

Answer (score 1):

The documentation was updated to address this issue.  If you add this in the beforeFilter method in AppController it resolves the problem.

```
$this->Auth->authorize = array(
    AuthComponent::ALL => array('actionPath' => 'controllers'),
    'Actions',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `$this->Auth->allow('initDB');` in beforeFilter()